# Sorting Counts in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am using Access 2013 and I have many Yes/No fields in a table named Survey. I have 25 survey questions that people check if true (yes), and I am querying the fields across the whole database to get a count of how many people entered Yes for each field.  A subset of my table is:

```
SurveyID AutoNumber
MemberID Number
Question1 Yes/No
Question2 Yes/No
Question3 Yes/No
```

etc...

The following query runs against the table above and is a subset of what I have, in that it only represents three fields:

```
SELECT Count(IIf([Survey]![Question1]=True,1,Null)) AS CountOfQuestion1, Count(IIf([Survey]![Question2]=True,1,Null)) AS CountOfQuestion2, Count(IIf([Survey]![Question3]=True,1,Null)) AS CountOfQuestion3
FROM Survey;
```

This works fine (the IIF bit is due to Access and its strangeness).  My question is, how do I now order this?  Each result comes out as a separate field in the query, and I need to order on the results of all the fields, not just one field.  For example, I might get the following:

```
CountOfQuestion1 34
CountOfQuestion2 7
CountOfQuestion3 11
```

I need to be able to sort this based on the numbers, so I know which count was the highest.  I hope to get:

```
CountOfQuestion1 34
CountOfQuestion3 11
CountOfQuestion2 7
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Normalize your table with a UNION query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you want the results in rows rather than in columns. One way to accomplish this is to use separate queries for each question count and then use the union operator to merge the results together like this:

```
SELECT 
 'Q1' AS Question, Count(IIf([Survey].[Question1]=True,1,Null)) AS QuestionCount
FROM Survey
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 'Q2' AS Question, Count(IIf([Survey].[Question2]=True,1,Null)) AS QuestionCount
FROM Survey
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 'Q3' AS Question, Count(IIf([Survey].[Question3]=True,1,Null)) AS QuestionCount
FROM  Survey
ORDER BY QuestionCount DESC
```

This would give output looking like this:

```
Question QuestionCount
-------- -------------
Q2       4
Q1       3
Q3       2
```

Comment: Yes!  That was it.  I always forget about Union queries and how to make the common field that unites the Selects.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Access Yes/No fields can be summed, so the following should work.
Select ABS(Sum(Question1)) as CountOfQuestion1, ABS(Sum(Question2)) as CountOfQuestion2
FROM Survey